# Update all MySQL entries if they have the same value

Tags: mysql, node.js

## Situation

I've created an application that displays the tasks to be done. These tasks are saved in a MySQL database and looks like this:

**Structure**

[id] [task_description] [customer_id] [status] [task_count]

**Example**

[42] ["Assemble box-xyz"] [42932] ["open"] [*x*]

## What I want

I'm using handlebars to display all the tasks. On my index page I'm displaying all the tasks with the neccessary information, like the description, customer, amount of open tasks etc.
In my table I do like to display the amount of open tasks like this:

```
<span>{{this.task_count}}</span>
```

As you can see, I just want to store the number of open tasks with the same customer id in each and every record of my database (which has the same customer id).

## My current code

I do like the display how many tasks with the same customer id are still open (that's the *x* in my example).
I've started with this:

```js
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open' ORDER BY customer_id DESC", (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (data in rows) {
      debug("Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: " + data);
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open' AND customer_id = ?", [rows[data].customer_id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        debug("Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: " + data);

        connection.query("UPDATE tasks SET task_count = ? WHERE customer_id = ?", [result.length, rows[data].customer_id], (err, update) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Since I have not only one entry, but several thousand, this does not work. It only updates the last entry. Once I debug it, I realize that it probably just ignores the for statement. My *data* variable is always at the maximum value of the *rows* length.

After several hours of research, I have not yet found a solution.

## Edit

I added a small debug function that shows my problem better.

**Output**

```
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: 0
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: 1
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: 2
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: 3
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable before the first query inside the for-statement: 4

[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: 4
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: 4
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: 4
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: 4
[DEBUG] [20.1.2023 13:21:31] Server: Current value of my data variable after the first query inside the for-statement: 4
```

## Solution

So, after I tried something different I found a solution. It's not really a good solutuion but it seems like it's working. See the code below.

```js
var task_count = 0;
var temp_id;

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open' ORDER BY customer_id DESC", (err, sqlQuery) => {

    for (var data in sqlQuery) {

      if (!temp_id) {
        temp_id = sqlQuery[data].customer_id;
        task_count++;
       } else {
         if (temp_id != sqlQuery[data].customer_id) {
           sqlQuery[data].task_count = connection.query("UPDATE tasks SET task_count = ? WHERE customer_id = ?", [task_count, temp_id]);
           task_count = 1;
           temp_id = sqlQuery[data].customer_id;
          }
          else {
            task_count++;
          }
       }

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting `result.length` from?

Comment: From the query above, where I select every open task with the same customer id.

Comment: Then that really ought to be part of the code you show

Comment: This part of the code is already shown. 

connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open' AND customer_id = ?", [rows[data].customer_id], (err, result) => {});

Comment: Oh woops, sorry, need glasses

Comment: All good! Happens to me a lot too! :)

Comment: I've added a small debug output of my issue.

Comment: The issue looks like a node.js / interface issue rather than a core MySQL issue; the SQL should work fine but it appears from what I gather than the wrong SQL is being called  by the interface code?

Comment: It looks like you need to confirm the structure of the `rows` variable which holds all the data. Node.js is not my strong point but in PHP this would be a numeric array of array of each row.

Comment: Yes, it's a node.js issue. I already found a solution which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after I tried something different I found a solution. It's not really a good solutuion but it seems like it's working. See the code below.

```js
var task_count = 0;
var temp_id;

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open' ORDER BY customer_id DESC", (err, sqlQuery) => {

    for (var data in sqlQuery) {

      if (!temp_id) {
        temp_id = sqlQuery[data].customer_id;
        task_count++;
       } else {
         if (temp_id != sqlQuery[data].customer_id) {
           sqlQuery[data].task_count = connection.query("UPDATE tasks SET task_count = ? WHERE customer_id = ?", [task_count, temp_id]);
           task_count = 1;
           temp_id = sqlQuery[data].customer_id;
          }
          else {
            task_count++;
          }
       }

    }
  });
});
```